# URL hack to create a lead with a different owner

Tags: urlhacking, ownership

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the owner when creating a new record via url hacking?

I am attempting to create a custom url button that will create a lead from a case with some information, pre-populated. I'm getting stuck with trying to set the owner of this new lead to a queue.

I believe I've found the lead owner field ID is "lea1" and I've tried a number of different combinations of `lea1=OWNERID`, `lea1=OWNERNAME`, `lea1_lkid=OWNERID` but nothing works.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can't you just use a workflow rule for that?

Comment: I can create a workflow, it's just an issue that I've run into a few times and haven't been able to find much info about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the owner using url hacking. I'm pretty sure that the default owner is always the current user.

You can create a workflow rule to change the owner when the record is saved.